# How to make the jQuery Sticky Float plug-in react dynamic page height changes?

Tags: jquery, position, live, sticky

I’m currently using StickyFloat http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat and am dynamically changing the height of the div the object sits in via jQuery, the changing of the CSS height works perfectly, but StickyFloat doesn’t recognise the new height of the div, it keeps the original height only.

Is there any way I can kill stickly float and re-enable it again?  It’s enabled with $('#floatCol').stickyfloat(); basically.
My question is identical to [How to make the jQuery Sticky Float plug-in react live to page changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093001/how-to-make-the-jquery-sticky-float-plug-in-react-live-to-page-changes) and it’s doing my head in big time.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this plugin, and in a mysterious way I see it was deleted from the jQuery repository just this month! anyway, I have a blog post with all information, and [re-posted the plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyFloat), and by now it was updated to work better, utilizing [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/).

### Stopping an item from "floating"

It is possible to just "kill" the plugin like so:
*Note, this will kill all the floating menus if you have multiple ones.*

> $(window).unbind('scroll.sticky')

### Updated blog post

View my blogpost about this plugin which contains the links:

http://dropthebit.com/74/sticky-floating-box/

### Update:

The plugin now supports sticking elements to the bottom and not only to the top

Comment: Thanks for the update to your plugin! I guess the jQuery plugin site got wiped out :S, so I"m glad I found this post here  http://blog.jquery.com/2011/12/08/what-is-happening-to-the-jquery-plugins-site/

Comment: Hi, any news about [fixing a div at the bottom](http://dropthebit.com/74/sticky-floating-box/#comment-2)?

Comment: Yes, all done, check it out and tell me what you think. there is an extra checkbox now that you can toggle the option `stickToBottom` to `true` so it will stick to the bottom.