# jQuery- stickyfloat.js update on new container height

Tags: jquery, css-float, sticky

This question definitely requires the use of a visual aid: http://jsfiddle.net/h8DUm/1/

The setup is a 2 column table that dynamically changes heights.  The left column has controls to adjust the sticky float height (in the right column) and to drop down a widget (in the left column).  The right column displays the sticky float.

It all seemingly works well except for one detail: when the menu is expanded and the sticky float div is resting at the bottom of the screen, AND THEN you collapse the menu, the sticky float div remains outside of the parent container until the window scrolls.

Is there any way to alter this behavior so that the stickyfloat div updates it's position automatically in this circumstance (or on a click)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you need?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436804/how-to-make-the-jquery-sticky-float-plug-in-react-dynamic-page-height-changes

Comment: That's the solution I am using already... it's an attached resource on the fiddle.